# Struggling to get data from a rss file into an array list in android

Tags: android, rss

I am creating a app that requires information that is in an rss file (will eventually be an actual feed but it doesn't exist yet) to be put into a recycler view, with each separate card showing only a snippet of information and when the user clicks onto the card it opens into another activity to show all the info.  However I am not sure how to access the local file as I would an actual live feed.  Any help would be much appreciated.

My rss file is in xml format and called dummy_RSS.rss.

I have a class to specify the the strings needed

```
public class EventViewDetails {

private String title;
private String location;
private String locLat;
private String locLong;
private String date;
private String timeStart;
private String timeFinish;
private String desc;

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public String getLocLat() {
    return locLat;
}

public void setLocLat(String locLat) {
    this.locLat = locLat;
}

public String getLocLong() {
    return locLong;
}

public void setLocLong(String locLong) {
    this.locLong = locLong;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getTimeStart() {
    return timeStart;
}

public void setTimeStart(String timeStart) {
    this.timeStart = timeStart;
}

public String getTimeFinish() {
    return timeFinish;
}

public void setTimeFinish(String timeFinish) {
    this.timeFinish = timeFinish;
}

public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}

public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}
}
```

I have a class to parse the data from the feed into the above strings

```
public class ParseEventDetails {

private String data;
private ArrayList<EventViewDetails> events;

public ParseEventDetails(String xmlData) {
    data = xmlData;
    events = new ArrayList<EventViewDetails>();
}

public ArrayList<EventViewDetails> getEvents() {
    return events;
}

public boolean process() {
    boolean operationStatus = true;
    EventViewDetails currentEvent = null;
    boolean inEntry = false;
    String textValue = "";
    XmlPullParserFactory factory = null;
    try {
        factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
        xpp.setInput(new StringReader(this.data));
        int type = xpp.getEventType();
        while (type != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            String tagName = xpp.getName();
            if (type == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("event")) {
                    inEntry = true;
                    currentEvent = new EventViewDetails();
                }
            } else if (type == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                textValue = xpp.getText();
            } else if (type == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                if (inEntry) {
                    if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("event")) {
                        events.add(currentEvent);
                        inEntry = false;
                    }
                    if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                        currentEvent.setTitle(textValue);
                    } else if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("location")) {
                        currentEvent.setLocation(textValue);
                    } else if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("date")) {
                        currentEvent.setDate(textValue);
                    } else if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("timestart")) {
                        currentEvent.setTimeStart(textValue);
                    } else if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("timefinish")) {
                        currentEvent.setTimeFinish(textValue);
                    } else if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("loclat")) {
                        currentEvent.setLocLat(textValue);
                    } else if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("loclong")) {
                        currentEvent.setLocLong(textValue);
                    } else if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("description")) {
                        currentEvent.setDesc(textValue);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        type = xpp.next();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        operationStatus = false;
    }
    return operationStatus;
}
}
```

I have the adapter for the recycler view

```
public class EventCalenderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EventCalenderAdapter.ViewHolder> {

String xmlData;

static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CardView cardView;
    TextView titleView;

    public ViewHolder(CardView card) {
        super(card);
        cardView = card;
        titleView = (TextView) card.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    }
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int i) {
    CardView v = (CardView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.event_task, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
    final Context context = viewHolder.titleView.getContext();
    viewHolder.titleView.setText(xmlData[i]);

    viewHolder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ((OnEventView) context).eventView(i);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return xmlData.length;
}
}
```

and I have my fragment

```
public class EventCalenderFragment extends Fragment {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
EventCalenderAdapter adapter;


public EventCalenderFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    adapter = new EventCalenderAdapter();
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_event_calender, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    return v;
}


}
```

As I have said I'm not sure how to access the local file or where to put the initial access.

Answer (score 0):

you must change access configuration in your phpmyadmin configuration to "allow any" and then the url will be something like that : localhost/your_php_project_name/your_php_file 
note that the file your_php_file must return xml data or file

Comment: I'm not using php at the moment as it is a local file in the same folder as the app

Comment: that's easier !! so just open the file directory and parse it.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that and in which activity should I put it

Comment: i thnik that you must puti it in the class ParseEventDetails in the method that parse the XML file. you must add an argument to this method that's specifie to the method the path of your XML file. this method will called in your mainActivity and there you put your path as the argument